# TPS55288 doesn't produce correct output

Tags: integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, layout

I have produced a design for a converter from 12-14 V to 12 V (3 A) using the [TPS55288](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps55288.pdf?ts=1633939568823) buck-boost converter.

Unfortunately, it is not producing the desired output.

I have laid it out as presented in the datasheet, and used same parts as suggested or same alternatives.

The output produces a 0.9 V. It seems as if it is charging a capacitance when I supply the input power.

The enable pin voltage is over the UVLO threshold. All values are according to the webench tool (https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=5B8D198B88C0AEB0).

[image: 12-24 to 12v3A schematic]
[image: 12v converter layout]

Pin 10 was routed after the production process.

What is missing?

Do I need to add anything?

Comment: Please show oscillograms and what you measure on which pin of the IC.

Comment: Why do you have SW1 & SW2 connected together to the 'output' side of the inductor? The typical application circuits in the datasheet show SW1 connected to the 'input' side.

Comment: They aren't connected. SW2 has two pins, labelled SW2_1 and SW2_2. These are connected together while SW1 is separate.

Comment: It seems that the power ground (pins 11 and 26) are only connected through vias, probably going to a ground plane on the bottom side. The output capacitors are connected to a ground fill on the top side. It creates a long and problematic return path for the high current. It would probably be better to stick to the proposed PCB, which otherwise seem to be mostly the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit works.

The problem was that it wasn't configured correctly via the I2C interface.

Other considerations wich would improve performance is designing the GND laypout better, and use 6 layers for better ground and signal routing to the surrounding systems.